# Including C header files from other directory

Tags: c, header, include

My understanding was always that by doing `#include <header.h>` it looks in the system include directories, and that `#include "header.h"` it looks in the local directory. But I was just looking at the python source code and it uses the `"header.h"` method to define headers in a sibling directory.

So in `py3k/Python/ast.c` it does `#include "Python.h"`. But `Python.h` is in `py3k/Include/Python.h`

Is this something common that I've just never seen, not having worked on any real large C project? How do I tell, at least my IDE, to look in `py3k/Include`?

**Update**
I figured out how to tell my IDE to include them, it was just me being stupid and a spelling error. But I'm more interested in why `""` works. Is that not the different between `""` and `<>`?

Comment: We need to know what IDE you are using.

Comment: Any particular IDE, or should we just guess?

Comment: For most IDEs there is some include directory setting in Project settings dialog box, there you can list your py3k/Include directory. It is hard to tell precise setting without knowing which IDE you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, it's Kdevelop, but I guess I'm more interested in how/why this works more than specifically making my IDE see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `#include <header>` and `#include "header"` look in *"implementation-defined places"*, i.e. it depends on the compiler you are using and its settings. For `#include <h>` it's usually some standard system include directories and whatever you configure the compiler to look in additionally.
The difference between the two versions is that if the search for `#include "header"` is not supported or fails, it will be reprocessed *"as if it read `#include <header>`"* (C99, *§6.10.2*).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

You need to somehow tell your compiler what directories to search in -- for GCC this means using the `-I` flag. Look it up for your combination of IDE / compiler.